# Magento 2.3 - Multiple Store if condition for different attributes

Tags: magento2

I have setup 2 Store Views i want to call different attributes based on store view on category and product detail pages.

Screenshot 1
https://nimb.ws/ljVb0W

if store id == 1

getResource()->getAttribute('fit-option1');
if ($attributeName) {
$labelValue = $attributeName->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
}
echo $labelValue;
 // END DISPLAY ATTRIBUTE
?>

else if store id == 2

getResource()->getAttribute('fit-option2');
if ($attributeName) {
$labelValue = $attributeName->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
}
echo $labelValue;
 // END DISPLAY ATTRIBUTE
?>

Answer (score 0):

You can separate your login by store id as below.

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
class Module extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_storeManager;    

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,        
        array $data = []
    )
    {        
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;        
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Get store identifier
     *
     * @return  int
     */
    public function getStoreId()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
    }

}
```

in your phtml file you can use above block and get store id as below.

```
if($block->getStoreId() == 1 } 
{
fit-option1
}

if($block->getStoreId() == 2 } 
{
fit-option2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please guide where to add below code

namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
class Module extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
protected $_storeManager;

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,        
    array $data = []
)
{        
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;        
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

/**
 * Get store identifier
 *
 * @return  int
 */
public function getStoreId()
{
    return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
}
```

}